# not fetching posts from firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch latest posts from the firebase. however, they do not appear in the app. what could be the cause of this?
Posts are registered and uploaded to the firestore, but do not appear in the app.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
  children: [
     if (isBannerAdReady)
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Container(
            width: bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
            height: bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
            child: AdWidget(ad: bannerAd),
          ),
        ),
      StreamBuilderWrapper(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        stream: postRef.orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (_, DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
          Review posts = Review.fromJson(snapshot.data());
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
            child: Posts(post: posts),
          );
        },
      ),
  ],
);
}
```

Help appreciated very much!

EDIT: I suspected it had something to do with the Username, that was in cyrillic. Editing profile and setting the username to latin letters, it worked. WHY? Firebase does not recognise cyrillic?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: got it! thanks! no suggestions as to why this does not fetch latest posts? logs do not show anything...